# how to add footer row dynamically for every 10 records in gridview using c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to break the gridview rows fro every 10 records in gridview.it is working fine but one more thing i need. That is for those 10 records i need add footer row and i have to calculate sum of those 10 rows in grid view .

This is My code for breaking the grid view...

```
protected void GVPartywisereport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        tempcounter = tempcounter + 1;
        if (tempcounter== 10)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "page-break-after: always;");
        }
    }
}
```

Please any body help me in that way.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - easiest way to do this would be to manipulate the back-end data-set or data-source to which your grid is bound rather than creating and inserting footer row in RowDataBound event.

Iterate over your data-set before binding data and add the summary row for every ten records.  Also add an extra property "IsPageSummary" in your data item that flags whether it is a summary record and not a real data item.

Inside RowDataBound event, grab the summary record separately using "IsPageSummary" property.  You will be to access underlying data object using e.DataItem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You may need to cast it though.  Once you grab and identify that it is a summary row, style it differently.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
protected void GVPartywisereport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex > 0 && e.Row.RowIndex % 10 == 0) //This will add after every 10th row
                {
                    int RowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
                    int DataItemIndex = e.Row.DataItemIndex;
                    int Columnscount = gv.Columns.Count;
                    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(RowIndex, DataItemIndex, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Normal);

                    TableCell tablecell = new TableCell();
                    tablecell.Text = "dynamic footer";
                    row.Cells.Add(tablecell);

                    this.gv.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);
                }
            }
}
```